# Difference between list.Count > 0 and list.Count != 0

Tags: c#, c++, performance, compare

I have a list of things. Is there any difference between `list.Count > 0` and `list.Count != 0`? Or any performance difference in these codes?

```
if (list.Count > 0)
    // do some stuff

if (list.Count != 0)
    // do some stuff
```

> note: `list.Count` Can't be less than ziro..

Comment: If that would make or break your program, you are in good shape.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1030001/4767498

Comment: Why do you care about it, regarding performance or correctness?

Comment: @qxg, I am just curious witch one is better and more standard in programmers world..

Comment: No difference. I would say not even a single cycle difference. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/ALU_Flags also kind of similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596300/performance-greater-smaller-than-vs-not-equal-to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271881/is-a-1-10-comparison-less-expensive-than-1-1000000

Comment: This is the kind of thing that could depend on the language, the type and implementation of `list`, and the type of `list.Count`.

Comment: There is no functional difference, when you trust that list.Count never returns a value less than zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's realistically no difference as the list can never have less than 0 items, but `==` for integral comparisons is wicked fast, so it's probably faster than `>`. A cooler looking approach is **`list.Any()`**.

(This is assuming by list you mean the List type or any built in IEnumerable/Collection)

Comment: I though in the same lines (upvoted), but in reality `list.Any()` seems to be slower! Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 3):

As explained by everyone, functionally there's no difference between `list.Count != 0` and `list.Count > 0` as list.Count can not be < 0.

I did a quick test, and it shows both `!= 0` and `> 0` are *almost* equally fast (and that's super fast). Linq's `list.Any()` is NOT as fast though!

Here's the test code (comparing 100000 times to magnify the difference)

```
static List<object> GetBigObjectList()
{
    var list = new List<object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new object());
    }
    return list;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myList = GetBigObjectList();
    var s1 = new Stopwatch();
    var s2 = new Stopwatch();
    var s3 = new Stopwatch();

    s1.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        var isNotEqual = myList.Count != 0;
    }
    s1.Stop();

    s2.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        var isGreaterThan = myList.Count > 0;
    }
    s2.Stop();

    s3.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        var isAny = myList.Any();
    }
    s3.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Time taken by !=    : " + s1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Time taken by >     : " + s2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Time taken by Any() : " + s3.ElapsedMilliseconds);            
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And it shows:

> Time taken by !=    : 0
>   Time taken by >     : 0
>   Time taken by Any() : 10

Comment: Years later, but I hope that you've heard of this library by now to use for benchmarks like this: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any difference between `list.Count > 0` and `list.Count != 0`?

Yes. The first one evaluates whether `list.Count` is greater than `0`. The second one evaluates whether it is not equal to `0`. "Greater than" and "not equal" are different things.

Comment: Can we assume that they mean a List which wouldn't have less than 0?

Comment: @TimothyStepanski You should ask OP. I am making no such assumption.

Comment: count of list is never less than zero so here they are same.

Comment: @juanchopanza You should make assumptions. You have all the info to make them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in the CPU registers level, the assembly commands for comparing two numbers will check those numbers bit by bit, and will activate some conditional flags to jump to specified lines. for Example:

```
cmp BL, BH     ; BL and BH are cpu registers
je EQUAL_Label       ; BL = BH
jg GREATER_Label     ; BL > BH
jmp LESS_Label       ; BL < BH
```

As you can see, `je`, `jg` or `jmp` commands are almost the most atomic commands that probably work on previous `cmp`(compare) command.
In conclusion we can say there is no significant performance difference between those compare command.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> In this particular scenario There is no typical difference between
>   these two. but `!=` and `>0` are entirely different. `>0` Execute only
>   when the count(conditional expression)greater than 0  where as `!=` Execute when the count(conditional expression)
>   greater than `0` as well as for less than `0`

```
if (list.Count > 0)
{
  // Execute only when the count greater than 0
}
if (list.Count != 0)
{
  // Execute only when the count not equal to 0
}
```

Comment: How can you know that? If you have access to OP's code, could you tell us what language it is written in, and what `list` is?

Comment: Ya well. List.Count will not be negative. What i am trying to say in my second statement is the difference between `>0` and `!=`

Answer (score 0):

I guess if ICollection.Count is type of `uint`, you will not have such question. See why ICollection.Count is `int` at [Why does .NET use int instead of uint in certain classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782629/why-does-net-use-int-instead-of-uint-in-certain-classes).

From readability point of view, `list.Count != 0` will cause thinking whether `Count` can be negative. So I prefer `list.Count > 0` personaly.